# How to make a smooth transition on CSS hover floating animation (infinite) for mouseout?

Tags: html, css

I created a CSS floating animation for hover on an image. On hover the image nicely floats up and down but when I mouseout the animation doesn't go back to the original state in a smooth manner. The idea would be, if the floating goes up, on the mouseout the image would float back down to the "ground" level. Is it possible to achieve it with just CSS?

I tried to add the transition to the hover state but because it's an infinite floating animation, it doesn't take into consideration in which Y position is the image. If I set it at -4px for translateY, and the image is at the -9px position it would result in a rough mouseout effect.

```css
.example-block {
  background: red;
  box-shadow: 0 27px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.6);
  transition: background 0.4s ease-out;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.example-block:hover {
  background: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  animation: levitate 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes levitate-in {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, -4px);
    box-shadow: 0 31px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.3);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
    box-shadow: 0 27px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.6);
  }
}
@keyframes levitate {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
    box-shadow: 0 27px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.6);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -9px);
    box-shadow: 0 36px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
    box-shadow: 0 27px 30px -15px rgba(21, 173, 250, 0.6);
  }
}
.example-block a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 500%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.example-block:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(33%);
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.example-block .image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out, transform 0.4s ease-out;
}
.example-block:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.2;
  transform: rotate(4deg) scale(1.1);
}
.example-block .svg {
  max-width: 41px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-block p-5 text-center">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="portfolio sample" class="image" />
  <a href="#"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/22x22" class="svg" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: is it acceptable to use javascript?

Comment: Its pretty much impossible to do this unless you use a `setInterval` to check over and over again the current `transform` rule value or you somehow can catch the value of the `transform` rule right before the `onmouseout` reverts the css to original state

Comment: @awesomeguy yes